# How to move line segment to certain direction using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

How can I move a Line Segment to a certain direction?
In my case i want to move the Line up north, so i need to change the y-coordinate somehow, I'm just not sure how to do this in ArcMap. Im using ArcGIS 10.1

Answer (score 2):

I did it via edit vertices > sketch properties. might be the easiest way.

Comment: For reference: Other GIS programs call it OffSet or Translate, Also Affine transformation can be used just offset